# Error when importing text from text file to pdf (reportlab, python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

I have this file: hello.txt, and this file have this text: Hello World and this is my code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
c = canvas.Canvas("file.pdf", pagesize=A4)
hello=open('files/hello.txt', encoding="utf-8").read()
c.drawString(10, 800, str(hello))
c.save()
```

But text inside of file.pdf looks like this:

[image: picture.png]

So, what is that black box which appears after an text? How can I remove it? Is there a better way to import text from text files to pdf with reportlab?

Comment: Does the text in the file end with a return?

Comment: Well it was an educated guess anyway. So we can state that you checked this, and the contents of your `hello` string indeed **only consists of** "Hello World", and absolutely nothing more? Its length is 11?

Comment: Yes, it only consists of "Hello World", nothing else.

Comment: @MarkusTorppa I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this one-liner on your string:
`your_text = ''.join([x for x in your_text if x in string.printable])`
This issue occurs because of non-printable characters.